# AfterEffects Scripting (JavaScript): Variable does NOT get the updated edittext value after running the script. Why?

Tags: javascript, text, get, var, after-effects

I'm pretty new to JavaScript and for better or worse I've started with the After Effects specialization of JavaScript (since I'm using AE for work). So to start with AE scripting, I decided to write a script (not UI) with functions to resize the active comp to specific dimensions and also be able to add new comps with specific dimensions, but when adding new comps, I'd also like the option to set the duration for the comp. **I've made an *edittext* with a default value of "30", but even when I change the input value, it sets the original "30" as the duration. Does it only get the original value of the *edittext* and not the updated value after the script is launched?** I'm a bit lost.

I don't have the original code available at the moment, but the basic logic of it is something like this (assume the rest of the code works):

```
var durPanel = myWindow.add("panel", undefined, "Set duration (seconds)");

var setDur = durPanel.add("edittext", undefined, "30");

var compButton = myWindow.add("button", undefined, "Add Comp");

var dur = Math.floor(setDur.text);

compButton.onClick = function() {
    app.project.items.addComp("New Comp", 1920, 1080, 1, dur, 25);
}
```

I might have missed something but that's kind of where I'm at. I'm confident in my logic so I can't see where the problem would be... **Is there a way to update the value of the input or something like that each time it changes?** I tried using *onChanging* or *onChange* on the *dur* variable as well, like `setDur.onChanging = function() {dur == dur}` or `{dur = dur}` or `{dur = Math.floor(setDur.text)}` or whatever, hoping it would kind of update the variable... Nothing worked. I tried adding a *button* to do the same, like `var apply = durPanel.add("button", undefined, "Apply"); apply.onClick = function() {dur = Math.floor(setDur.text)}`. I also tried linking it to another *var*, like `var getDur = Math.floor(setDur.text); var dur = getDur;` I even tried the *getElementbyId* method (which I'm pretty sure I don't know how to use in AE scripting, if it even is possible). I'm honestly surprised nothing has worked so far. It seems like it should be rather simple. I've seen some ways to solve it in regards to HTML (mostly by *getElement*), but not in regards to AE.

***Why aren't there more AE scripting resources out there?!***

**Help...  :(**

*PS: If you know of any quality AE scripting guides, I'd really appreciate the suggestion.*

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.